# ARIMA Minute Data and Holidays

Tags: time-series, arima, seasonality, statsmodels

I have a minutely dataset for a year duration. It has a daily seasonality. This would imply a seasonal period of 1440 according to https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods/ .

I thought of using the SARIMA (,,)×(,,) model with the following parameters :
order : (,,) - (6,0,0) - ACF and PACF hinted at a pure AR process

I have trouble determining the (,,).

- 1440

However even for (,,) = (1,0,0), the model.fit takes a really long time.

train size - 216,000 data points.

I suspect it is due to the high 's' value.

Is SARIMA not meant to handle minute level data with daily seasonality?

Answer (score 1):

Well of course you have a computation problem since you have lag of 1440 and you probably use maximum likelihood estimator (conditional) so to initialize it has to solve a 1440 linear system + multiplying more than 1440 matrices by each other ...

So it's quiet impossible to use SARIMA here, the best way would be to go with ARIMAX with the creation of a dummy variable that is 1 every 1440, 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a3382%2016%20minute details how to model data taken 15 minutes apart. This is easily extended to readings taken 1 minute apart . The whole idea is that one can and should use deterministic dummies and develop 60 models by using daily predictions.